Curve with profile progressively losing alignment
I'm working on a gothic rib vault, and I'm trying to add the ribs. But the ribs don't align with the edges visually. Here's an example. The red part is the rib of the vault. The higher it goes, the more it loses it's shape visually. The bottom of the ribs looks wider, compared to the top. I created the ribs by extracting the edges of the vault, then converting to curves. Editing the curve manually is not feasible, as I am working on a modular set 



the angle gets smaller as the faces get larger, burying your red geometry: https://i.sstatic.net/WoSbOrwX.png

somehow i missed that. is there any way to fix this based on the vault geometry? i.e without manual adjustment

Maybe shrinkwrap or geometry nodes. I didn't propose anything (and write an answer) because it requires some design choice on how you actually want it to look as the geometry changes.Maybe it should bend based on the geometry it sticks to.
